I have a problem where when I tap on a cell to display a picker, the picker is being displayed on the next table view cell
extension ContactsTourViewController {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Contacts count: \(contacts.count)")
        return contacts.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ContactsTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? ContactsTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        
        let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)"
        cell.phoneLabel.text = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue ?? "Error: Phone number missing"

        cell.delegate = self
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ContactsTableViewCell {
            cell.roleTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    
    func didSelectRole(_ role: String?, forCell cell: ContactsTableViewCell) {
        guard let indexPath = contactsTableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
            return
        }
        
                
        // Reload only the cell that was updated
        contactsTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        print("Selected role: \(role ?? "None") for contact at \(indexPath.row)")
        
    }
} 

I stored my contact in this property class
ContactsTourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ContactsTableViewCellDelegate  {
    
    
    var contacts: [CNContact] = []  {
        didSet {
            contactsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    } 

the I fetched my contact using this function and loaded them in my table view
       private func fetchContacts() {
           let store = CNContactStore()
           
           store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { granted, error in
               guard granted else {
                   print("Access denied")
                   return
               }
               
               let keysToFetch = [
                   CNContactGivenNameKey,
                   CNContactFamilyNameKey,
                   CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
                   CNContactImageDataKey
               ] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
               
               let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
               DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                   var fetchedContacts: [CNContact] = []
                   do {
                       try store.enumerateContacts(with: request) { contact, stop in
                           fetchedContacts.append(contact)
                       }
                       DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
                           self?.contacts = fetchedContacts
                           self?.contactsTableView.reloadData()
                       }
                   } catch {
                       print("Failed to fetch contacts:", error)
                   }
                   
               }
           }
       }
}
extension ContactsTourViewController {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Contacts count: \(contacts.count)")
        return contacts.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ContactsTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? ContactsTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        
        let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)"
        cell.phoneLabel.text = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue ?? "Error: Phone number missing"

        cell.delegate = self
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ContactsTableViewCell {
            cell.roleTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    
    func didSelectRole(_ role: String?, forCell cell: ContactsTableViewCell) {
        guard let indexPath = contactsTableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
            return
        }
        
                
        // Reload only the cell that was updated
        contactsTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        print("Selected role: \(role ?? "None") for contact at \(indexPath.row)")
        
    }
}


My first cell in the table view is blank too

Which function displays the picker?

hi Paul sorry I figured it out. Thank you
